# how to change the url on click or on submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap 3 with a long form which is divided in five tabs and if `tab one` is active means url is `domain.com/profiles/1/edit?tab=one` and i click on `tab two` or lets say if i click on submit button of `tab two` than i want to modify the url as `domain.com/profiles/1/edit?tab=two`. i dont know, if it can be done or not... may be it can be done via javascript but i don't know how.

Thanks for your time.

```
# Tabs nav
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'one' %>">
    <a href="#one"  data-toggle="tab">Tab one</a>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'two' %>">
    <a href="#two"  data-toggle="tab">Tab two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'three' %>">
    <a href="#three" data-toggle="tab">Tab three</a>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'four' %>">
    <a href="#four" data-toggle="tab">Tab four</a>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'five' %>">
    <a href="#five"  data-toggle="tab">Tab five</a>
  </li>
</ul>

# Tabs content
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="<%= if (params[:tab] == 'one' || !params[:tab])then 'tab-pane active'  else 'tab-pane' end %>" id="one">
    <%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :fname, "First name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :fname, :class => "form-control required"  %>
      <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary"  %>
    <% end %>
  </div> <!-- tab one ends -->

  <div class="<%= if params[:tab] == 'two' then 'tab-pane active'  else 'tab-pane' end %>" id="two">
    <%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :lname, "Last name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :lname, :class => "form-control required"  %>
      <%= f.submit "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary"  %>
    <% end %>
  </div> <!-- tab two ends -->
  # same goes on
  <!-- tab three ends -->
  <!-- tab four ends -->
  <!-- tab five ends -->
</div>
```

My main motive is, when i submit the form of `tab one`, after saving page it should display `tab one` active.
when i submit the form of `tab two`, after saving page it should display `tab two` active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to specify to return to a certain section on your page from your controller, you can use 'anchor' (to specify a div id to return to), or you can create the url yourself. I would normally specify an id for each tab (so that my url would look more like "/edit#tab_one", and then in my controller action, do

```
redirect_to :edit, :anchor => "tab_one"
```

but since you're doing more of a query type of url, you can just make the url path like so:

```
url = edit_profile_path(@profile)
new_url = url + "?tab=one"
redirect_to new_url
```

The trickiest part really is knowing which tab is active. So, you can pass this is a hidden param in each tab's form:

```
f.hidden_field :tab, :value => "one"  # and 'two' in the second tab, etc.
```

and then in your controller doing this:

```
tab = params[:tab]
url = edit_profile_path(@profile)
new_url = url + "?tab=" + tab
redirect_to new_url
```

Comment: actually, sorry, looks like you're already doing something with a params[:tab] so just use that